# Check if part of a String exists in HashMap

Tags: java, loops, optimization, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` of 60k key/value pairs.

I have 100 strings and out of those 100 strings one has a substring which exists in `HashMap`.

I would have to repeat this process thousand times. Is there is an efficient approach to do this?

Let's say, the hash contains like:

> journal of america, rev su arabia, comutational journal, etc..

And the strings like:

> published in rev su arabia
>
> the publication event happened in
>
> computationl journal 230:34

The first and third string contains the key/value in the hash and I need to find out those.

**Code** (not efficient)

```
private String contains(String candidateLine)
{
    Iterator<String> it = journalName.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        String journalName = it.next();
        if (candidateLine.contains(journalName))
            return journalName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Those don't look like hashes to me.  Do you mean to say that you are storing these values in a `HashMap`?

Comment: yes, its hashmap, corrected the question

Comment: Not a solution, but for `journalName` at least `LinkedHashMap` is much more efficient in my experience than plain `HashMap`

Comment: How would you search for the substrings efficiently using linkedhashmap?

Comment: What is the longest number of words in a journal name? 3? In a given text, find all possible 3-word phrases and put them in a Set. Then find the [intersection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) with `journalName`. If the intersection is non-empty you have the journal name(s).

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirements, the only answer is: wrong design point. You are basically asking how to efficiently support "full text" search capabilities. And for that problem, the answer is: don't do it yourself.

Meaning: forget about re-inventing the wheel here. Instead, pick up an existing solution, such as Lucene (library) or products such as Solr or ElasticSearch ( see [here](https://www.toptal.com/database/full-text-search-of-dialogues-with-apache-lucene) for more information).

You see, most likely we are looking at a "real world" production problem here. So even when you find a clever way to build your own data structure to support your current requirements, chances are high that sooner or later "more" requirements will be coming your way.

Therefore I seriously suggest that clarify the exact problem to solve, and then identify that existing product that best solves the problem. Otherwise you will be fighting uphill battles like forever.

Comment: I have to find the journal name in text(100 lines). I already have compiled list of thousands for journals. I just wouldn't know which line and which part of it would contain the journal name. Lucene might be solution here. But I would like to know whats your opinion here.